# Django error: cannot open shared file

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the following Django error:

```
ImportError at /

libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I assume this is because the app is looking for python 2.6 and the system only has python 2.7.  Is that right?

If so, how can I install the old version on Ubuntu Server 14.04?  Preferably using `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu in particular, you can use the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes) to install old and new Python versions.

However, I would suggest updating your project and environment to use the system standard Python, if possible, rather than installing an old version. Things to check:

- Do your Python scripts have a shebang pointing to a non-default Python? (In other words, check that files like manage.py start with `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`, not other options like `#!/usr/bin/env python2.6`.)
- Are you running out of a virtualenv? Virtualenvs are created for a particular version of Python, so if you created it on another system or an older installation, it's probably easiest to delete and recreate it.

Comment: Thanks.  I've installed python2.6 using that PPA.  The project is a legacy app and part of the task is updating it.  but I need to get it working first.